# Where does the Module Manager in zf2 gets registered as a Service of the Service Manager?

Tags: zend-framework2

i'm reading the code of Zendframework 2, in order to understand it better. I can't find the place in the code where the Module Manager gets registered in the Service Manager as a service. Any help is much appreciated.

Greetings,
Todor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\Zend\Mvc\Application::init() [creates](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/release-2.3.1/library/Zend/Mvc/Application.php#L250) the service manager, passing in a [ServiceManagerConfig](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/release-2.3.1/library/Zend/Mvc/Service/ServiceManagerConfig.php#L19), which by default defines a few [factories](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/release-2.3.1/library/Zend/Mvc/Service/ServiceManagerConfig.php#L37).

So in a typical \Zend\Mvc\Application, the module manager get wired into the ServiceManager via that factory.  The factory is responsible for [creating the ModuleManager](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/release-2.3.1/library/Zend/Mvc/Service/ModuleManagerFactory.php#L132) the first time it's requested.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and sorry for the late reply.